project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com is missing and I have xxx@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com instead
I am experiencing difficulties in my google cloud project.
Today I tried to deploy function from firebase functions in gen1 and I got an error, so I checked the logs and I saw that the serveur can't connect to project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com and so I checked on google cloud and yeah there is no @appspot.gserviceaccount.com at all in my service account but only @project.iam.gserviceaccount.com and I can only create new project.iam account,can someone please help me to fix this issue ?



Can you paste the exact error that you got?

Look at this question maybe some of the answers will be helpful in your case - Error on google function deploy, service account doesn't exist
